# Execute javascript code inside iframe "src" that already contains text

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I've set up an app to test different ways to execute XSS attakcs, it will add anything I write in a textbox as an addition to iframe src value.

But the src already contains a string inside of it. So if i write something like javascript:alert('123'), the final iframe src will look like this
`<iframe src="blahblahjavascript:alert('123')>`

Is there a way to still execute javascript code inside of that iframe? (escape the src?)

Tried adding \n, closing quotes, adding special utf characters.

Comment: Why do you need to execute JS through src?

Comment: @almarc Kinda unrelated, but I found [this](https://github.com/s0md3v/XSStrike) on GitHub recently. Might be worth checking it out.

Answer (score 1):

Overall letting users change the iFrame source does not seem like a safe thing to do without escaping the result (at the very least). In terms of XSS attacks, you should assume every user input is dangerous and handle it accordingly. Never trust anything a client sends you. Never trust any user input. Always assume user input and things sent to you are dangerous and handle accordingly.

It doesn't matter if it's an iFrame source or whatever. The point is to escape everything.

What if I were to enter `"><h1>XSS</h1><iframe src="` into your text field? Would your input look like `<iframe src="blahblah"><h1>XSS</h1><iframe src="">` or something similar?

If so, I could just put a script tag there instead and make it a lot worse.

Comment: Yeah, I've mentioned that it's an XSS test. Probably it sounds like I have an app already and it's some kind of attempt to make it more secure.
Actually, the app I wrote is only to try different XSS techniques.

Comment: I thought of that. Tried closing the quote and puting another HTML tag there.
But it treats all the text inside (including quotes) as text. It looks like this
`<iframe src="blahblah"<h1>XSS<h1>">`

Comment: @almarc That doesn't make sense. The example you just posted has 3 quotes. Where is the other closing one? And how it is ignoring the `">` at the beginning that I posted?

Comment: That's the point. The app appends the added value to `src` as a string. str + str.
So the quote after `blahblah` is treated as text. I can't color it here, but I guess you got the point.
And the same about ">, it just treast all of that as a string.

Comment: @almarc Treats it as a string? Not exactly sure what you mean by that. But I think my original point still stands. Escape and don't trust anything the user or client can input or send to you.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ss59A9v
Here is what I mean. All that's colored blue is a string, and the outer quotes are brown as actual code.
Even though there is a quote inside that two src="" quotes, it's not treated as actual code by the browser.
And yes, i tried closing it with >. This one is just a different example.

Comment: @almarc Can you edit your question with a reproducible example so we can play with it? I'd also like to know why my answer isn't good enough and what the hesitation is with escaping it? Is there a reason you don't want to escape it? Why not just be safe and escape it? If you have an idea of an attack, just because you can't execute it, doesn't mean you shouldn't work to prevent it.